# delete/ del command not working- CMD

Tags: windows, command-line

I am trying to delete tens of thousands of files in thousands of folders. After running `del /f/s/q foldername > nul` my cursor returns/ enters to the next line without showing my location as usual (`E:\foldername>`). Nothing else happens in the cmd prompt.

Although my files were deleted in all the folders, I can't type my next command (`rmdir /s/q foldername`). I also can't type anything else like `dir`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try closing the cmd prompt and creating a new cmd prompt. Then try DIR<ENTER>   dir isn't in the path, it should work.. If it doesn't then try a new cmd prompt 'cos your current one may have be playing up in some way.  You can close it with task manager for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing `> nul` in your command means you do not want any output of the command displayed on screen.

Deleting a massive amount of files of course takes time, so it is very likely that your command is still running.

Remove the `> nul` part from your command and run it again so you can actually see it working.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense, it indeed needs some time to delete all the files. Now it writes all the deleted files to screen and I am able to see it is running.